# Python parsing Json - "X is None" doesn't catch empty objects

Tags: python, json, empty-list

I am new to Python and I am trying to parse a Json file using Python. 
The Json file is a nested file. While I am trying to exact the "conversation_id" item, the list that contains this item, and the list above sometimes can be empty. I am hoping to replace empty list as string "N/A", otherwise grab the item. Code I am using is as following:

```
for log in data['logs']:
    print("Processing log "+log['log_id'])

    logcolumns=[]

    if log['request'] is None:
            logcolumns.append("N/A")
    elif log['request']['context'] is None:
           logcolumns.append("N/A")
    else:
        logcolumns.append(log['request']['context']['conversation_id'])
try:
        print("\t".join(logcolumns),file = conv_tsv)
    except KeyError:pass

del logcolumns
```

Traceback error I got is

```
Processing log cafa1077-f479-4c55-ac34-3bc3ebbb41fc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conversation_log_2.py", line 43, in <module>
    logcolumns.append(log['request']['context']['conversation_id'])
KeyError: 'conversation_id'
```

The "request" list that is associated with this log id is shown as below in the json file:

```
{"request": {"input": {}, "context": {}},
```

A full request list would be like this:

```
{"request": {"input": {"text": "haha"}, "context": {"conversation_id": "328d2320-f488-4f46-b71f-6cdfb1b79106", "system": {"dialog_stack": [{"dialog_node_s": "root"}], "dialog_turn_counter": 1, "dialog_request_counter": 1, "_node_output_map_s": "{\"Welcome\":[0,1,0]}", "branch_exited_s": "true", "branch_exited_reason_s": "completed"}}},
```

When I went to the output file, which is `conv.tsv`, there is `N/A` in the output.

Comment: Well why would it? `{} is not None`.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can catch the empty strings then? I tried `if !log['request']` `if log['request']==0` but it always came back as syntax error.

Comment: `if not log['request']:`; Python doesn't use `!` for negation like that (see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations), and `'' != 0`.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me how to catch empty object in python too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have the syntax quite moodled up. Is the `try/except` supposed to be wrapping the `if/elif`? Do you actually want `if/elif`s?

Note that `log['request'] is None`  does not test that the key's value is an empty dict.

You can use the `.get` method that returns a default when the key is not found:

```
logcolumns.append(log.get('request', {}).get('context', {}).get('conversation', 'N/A'))
```

Or better still, use a `try/except` to append the default value if any of the keys in missing:

```
try:
    logcolumns.append(log['request']['context']['conversation_id'])
except KeyError:
    logcolumns.append('N/A')
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am not trying to append log[ 'request'], neither am I trying to append log['request']['context']. I only want to append log['request']['context']['conversation_id']. Using your approach, I changed my code to:  logcolumns.append(log.get('request', 'N/A'))
    logcolumns.append(log.get('request', {}).get('context', 'N/A'))
    logcolumns.append(log['request']['context']['conversation_id']) it gave me this error: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found

Comment: The second approach worked great for me. Thanks! Also you were right about my wrong placed `try/except`. It should have been placed for each item not at the end. I don't actually want 'if/elif' though.

Comment: sorry I thought upvoting means accepting. I just accepted. Thanks.